# JSON request fails type'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to populate a profile page with data fetched from the API by following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-fetching-parsing-json-data-c019ddddaa34). I don't know why but I get the next error "Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast" and I literally looked up everywhere and tried everything. 
My model is this:

```
class Profile {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String city;
  final String street;
  final String streetNo;
  final String postcode;
  final String state;
  final String country;
  final String phoneNumber;
  final String languages;
  final String certified;

  Profile._({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.city, this.street, this.streetNo, this.postcode, this.state, this.country, this.phoneNumber, this.languages, this.certified});

  factory Profile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Profile._(
  firstName: json['response']['user']['first_name'],
  lastName: json['response']['user']['last_name'],
  city: json['response']['user']['city'],
  street: json['response']['user']['street'],
  streetNo: json['response']['user']['street_no'],
  postcode: json['response']['user']['postcode'],
  state: json['response']['user']['state'].toString(),
  country: json['response']['user']['country'].toString(),
  languages: json['response']['languages'].toString(),
  certified: json['response']['certified'].toString()

  );
}
}
```

And the API request is this:

```
_fetchAndNavigate() async {
    _sharedPreferences = await _prefs;
    var uri = host + '/translators/' + AuthUtils.getId(_sharedPreferences);
      var token =AuthUtils.getToken(_sharedPreferences);

    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
       'Authorization': 'JWT $token'
     };

    final response = await http.get(
      uri,
      headers: requestHeaders
    );
      if(response.statusCode == 200) {
        (json.decode(response.body) as List)
          .map((data) => new Profile.fromJson(data))
        .toList();
        print(response);
        print(list);
      }

  }
```

The debugger throws the error when it analyzes the "as List" but I can't understand why.
I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong or if it's some kind of bug. Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried `Map<String, dynamic> myMap = new Map<String, dynamic>.from(/*Your Source*/ );`? Seems like it would work for you.

Comment: Can you also paste sample api response?

Comment: @MarkLyons I figured it out meanwhile but this was the correct answer. To be honest, I don't get why this works tho'.